# Android application crashing when viewing custom view in activity

Tags: android, canvas, android-activity, custom-view

I'm getting following error when I try to run my app:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{g.companieshouse.companieshouse/g.companieshouse.companieshouse.GraphActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class g.companieshouse.companieshouse.DrawGraphTest
```

My custom class draws a canvas:

```
public class DrawGraphTest extends View {

    int mWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int mHeight = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    public DrawGraphTest(Context context) {
        super(context);
        //Various paints and such...

        //Set point to middle of screen
        point1 = new Point(mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //Draw various stuff to canvas
}
```

The activity:

```
public class GraphActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DrawGraphTest drawGraphTest;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph);
        drawGraphTest = (DrawGraphTest)findViewById(R.id.drawGraphTest);

    }
}
```

XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GraphActivity">

<g.companieshouse.companieshouse.DrawGraphTest
    android:id="@+id/drawGraphTest"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I also wanted to ask if it is possible to scale what is drawn in "DrawGraphTest" class so that it fits within the bounds of the custom view on the activity?

Currently it is set up to fit the entire screen of whatever device the app is being run on (see point1), Cheers!

Comment: can you post the full xml for the activity?

Comment: As per the error you posted, there is some issue in your xml file

Comment: @SteelToe I have updated the post to show the full XML, thanks!

Comment: there is an error in the xml, you did not close the constraint layout, close it by adding a  closing tag for the constraint layout on bottom

Comment: What is the package declaration in your DrawGraphTest class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one of the constructors which is used to inflate layouts via XML:

```
public class DrawGraphTest extends View {

    int mWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int mHeight = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    // This constructor is used only if you instantiate your view dinamically (java)
    public DrawGraphTest(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    // You are missing this constructor.. Add it so Android can instantiate your view via xml
    public DrawGraphTest(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        //Various paints and such...
        //Set point to middle of screen
        point1 = new Point(mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //Draw various stuff to canvas
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I don't suppose you have any thoughts or can point me in the right direction on how I can scale what is drawn in the canvas to fit the custom view in the activity? Currently most of the canvas drawing is cut off by the bounds of the custom view

Comment: Raise a new question with screenshots etc.. Then, we'll try to help you